# Batch making text file input not copied

Tags: batch-file

I make a batch file which first creates a couple files, and then opens it

For one file I did

```
Set txt = (some text) """" & (some more text)
```

And then it puts that text into a `.txt` file but, everything after the `&` doesn't get copied. Only the things in front of it.

I would want to copy the whole thing, not only the things in front of the `&`

Comment: Use the recommended syntax, `Set "VariableName=Variable Value"`

Comment: Pretty sure I've tried that. For some reason, it didnt put anything into the file at all. I'll try again as I am at home. Thanks tho

Comment: Well how about trying it again, and then updating your question to include that recommended syntax, to prevent others from reading it and thinking you've done it wrong, when you apparently haven't. What you have posted doesn't even define a variable `%txt%` it defines `%txt %`! There is nothing there which puts anything into a `.txt` file either! and I'm not sure why you've used the term 'copied', because you're not copying anything!

Comment: What `.txt` file are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put carret `^` just before the ampersand `&` character, it need to be escaped because it have special meaning in windows shell scripting